# how can different shapes of thermometer bulbs effect response to temperature changes?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Two thermometers are constructed in the same way except that one has a spherical bulb and the one, cylindrical. Which one will respond quickly to temperature changes and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule a shape with a low surface area to volume ratio will cool or heat more slowly that a shape with a high surface area to volume ratio.

The sphere is the shape with the lowest possible surface area to volume ratio, so all else being equal spheres will heat or cool more slowly than any other shape. That means a thermometer with a spherical bulb will respond more slowly than one with a differently shaped bulb. However it is only the rate of response that is affected. Both thermometers will end up showing the same temperature.